# Creating new variables using different datasets

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge

I'm trying to merge two datasets that have different structures. The first dataset contains indicators on a country level, per country and age class and looks like this:

```
  country age_class nb_birth nb_singleton nb_twin   prob_twin nb_under_5_dead nb_under_5_dead_singleton
1     AO7     15-19       28           28       0 0.000000000               2                         2
2     AO7     20-24     1133         1123      10 0.008826125             107                       101
3     AO7     25-29     3338         3256      82 0.024565608             327                       302
4     AO7     30-34     4152         4059      93 0.022398844             425                       402
5     AO7     35-39     4934         4784     150 0.030401297             545                       509
6     AO7     40-44     4840         4647     193 0.039876033             726                       660
```

The second datasets contains indicators on an individual level, per mother and looks like this:

```
           caseid   weight country age age_class   region region_type    education  wealth parity
1     00010001 02 1.086089     AO7  38     35-39 benguela       rural no education poorest      7
2     00010002 02 1.086089     AO7  40     40-44 benguela       rural no education poorest      6
3     00010002 03 1.086089     AO7  16     15-19 benguela       rural no education poorest      1
4     00010003 02 1.086089     AO7  43     40-44 benguela       rural      primary poorest      8
5     00010004 02 1.086089     AO7  25     25-29 benguela       rural no education poorest      6
6     00010006 01 1.086089     AO7  26     25-29 benguela       rural no education poorest      4
```

As you can see, the variables "country" and "age class" are shared. What I'm trying to do is assign indicators from the country dataset to every row in the mother dataset. I would like to end up with something like this:

```
           caseid   weight country age age_class    [...]   nb_births nb_singleton nb_twin prob_twin
1     00010001 02 1.086089     AO7  38     35-39    [...]        4934         4784     150    0.0304
2     00010002 02 1.086089     AO7  40     40-44    [...]        4840         4647     193    0.0399
3     00010002 03 1.086089     AO7  16     15-19    [...]          28           28       0    0.0000
```

In the end, all mothers from the same country and age class will have the same values for variables from the country dataset.

I am working with the dplyr package and have played with the join functions and mutate function. But I can't figure it out.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show your join attempts? Sounds like you are on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the only thing you need to do is a `dplyr::left_join`. `df1` is the country dataset and `df1` is the mothers dataset.

```
left_join(df2, df1)
## Joining, by = c("country", "age_class")
##        caseid   weight country age age_class [...] nb_singleton nb_twin  prob_twin nb_under_5_dead nb_under_5_dead_singleton
## 1 00010001 02 1.086089     AO7  38     35-39 [...]         4784     150 0.03040130             545                       509
## 2 00010002 02 1.086089     AO7  40     40-44 [...]         4647     193 0.03987603             726                       660
## 3 00010002 03 1.086089     AO7  16     15-19 [...]           28       0 0.00000000               2                         2
## 4 00010003 02 1.086089     AO7  43     40-44 [...]         4647     193 0.03987603             726                       660
## 5 00010004 02 1.086089     AO7  25     25-29 [...]         3256      82 0.02456561             327                       302
## 6 00010006 01 1.086089     AO7  26     25-29 [...]         3256      82 0.02456561             327                       302
```

`dplyr::left_join` keeps all the rows from the first data.frame and adds matching rows from the second data.frame.